# Support of a regular measure Reg

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $K$ be compact, Hausdorff space but not necessarily metrizable. Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the Borel $\sigma$ field over $K$ and $\mu$ be a positive Regular Borel measure on $K$. Let $S$ be a subset of $K$ not necessarily in $\mathfrak{M}$. Suppose for all Baire sets $E\subseteq K\setminus S$, $\mu(E)=0$. Can I conclude that $Supp(\mu)\subset S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K=[0,1]$, $\mathfrak{R}$ its usual Borel $\sigma$-field. and $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, $S= K\setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
Then, for all Baire sets $E \subset \mathbb{Q}, \mu(E)=0$, while $$\text{supp}(\mu)= K \ne S$$

Comment: According to my notations is it possible to conclude that, $\int_Sf(t)d\mu (t)=\int_Kf(t)d\mu(t)$ if $S$ is Borel and $f\in C(K)$. Here remember that $\mu(E)=0$ if $E\subseteq K\setminus S$ is a Baire set.

Comment: Still false.<br>
$ K=[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the product topology <br> 
$ \mathbb{0}= (0,0,...) \in K$<br>
$\mu(A) = \mathbb{\delta}_{\mathbb{0}}$<br>
$S=K\setminus \{\mathbb{0}\}$<br>
$f := 1$<br>
Because $\{\mathbb{0}\}$ is not a Baire set (while it is compact), the only Baire set contained in $S^{c}$ is $\emptyset$,  and 
$$1 = \int_{K}fd\mu \ne 0= \int_{S} fd\mu $$